# Find string between 2 known values in textbox in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#

**Example:** I want to find 1234 in a string named target:

```
string target = "55555>>><<[1234]<>>>788";
```

How can I find the number between [,] without knowing how much digits between [], before[ or after ]?  I need a small code for my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions

Comment: Can you have more than set of [] in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for regular expressions

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "55555>>><<[1234]<>>>788";

            Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(\d*)\]");
            Match match = r.Match(str);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

the above code has the following output

```
1234
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

// Declare target
string target = "55555>>><<[1234]<>>>788";

// Declare the regular expression
Regex regex = new Regex(
    @"(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])",
    RegexOptions.None
);

// Use regex to get value
string number = regex.Match(target).Value;

// Convert to number (optional)
int value = 0;
int.TryParse(number, out value);

// Note: value will be 0 if no matches are found.
```

What this regex does:

The first bit `(?<=\[)` is a "look behind". It ensures that a bracket proceeds the numbers.  You have to escape it with a backslash because brackets are special characters in a regex.

The middle bit `[0-9]+` looks for one or more of any digit.  If you wanted zero or more, you could use a star instead of a plus: `[0-9]*`

The last bit `(?=\])` is a "look ahead" similar to the "look behind". Again the bracket is escaped.

The output will be only the numbers without the brackets but only when the numbers are surrounded by brackets.

Comment: when i put the code, VS could not understand Regex, should i add something in the beginning of the code?

Comment: one more question... how to add regex value to the string named "target" ?

Comment: You don't want to add the regex value to the string.  You will create the Regex object which has a `Match` method which you use to get the value.  I updated my answer with and example.

Comment: what value are you starting with and what value are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex which does the trick:

```
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Match("55555>>><<[1234]<>>>788", @"(?:\[)(?<Data>[^\]]+)(?:\])").Groups["Data"].Value);
// 1234 is outputed
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should suffice:

```
var match = Regex.Match("55555>>><<[1234]<>>>788", ".*\[(.+)\].*");

var value = match.Groups[1].Value; //= "1234"
```

If value should always be a number you can replace `(.+)` with `(\d+)` as in the other answers.

`.+` means any character
`\d` means any digit 0 to 9.

Comment: If you use `.*` or `\d*` then this allows for 0 characters between []. Using `+` ensures there is at least one character/digit.